# Creating a Custom Element don't seem to work on YouTube but works on Vimeo website

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, youtube, web-component, ecmascript-5

I've been making a chrome extension and have also been learning about custom elements. So I made a made a script that uses Custom Elements and injected it into YouTube's website on Chrome and it throws this error when I try to create my custom element:

[image]
But for some reason, my code works perfectly fine on any Vimeo video.

So I experimented and noticed something interesting you might be able replicate.

1) Open up Chrome or FireFox

2) Goto some Youtube video (like this one) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQPUnk12nTM

3) Open up the console

4) Paste in this code:

```
class TestElement extends HTMLElement
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
};
window.customElements.define("test-element", TestElement);
var testElement = document.createElement("test-element");
```

I got the exact same error.

[image]

5) Now, goto some other site (https://vimeo.com/386352766) and repeat those steps.

**I didn't get an error when I pasted that code in..Why? Why do I get an error on YouTube, but not Vimeo?**

Answer (score 1):

[custom-elements-es5-adapter](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs) is an approach to getting custom elements to work in an ES5 environment. It works by loading the adapter, followed by your code compiled for ES5. If the adapter is being used classes have to be compiled for ES5.

Sites can create two builds, an ES6 without the adapter for modern browsers and ES5 with the adapter for older browsers. In that scenario your code snippet would work fine in modern browsers. However it appears YouTube is shipping ES5 to all browsers so the adapter is throwing an error for the class syntax which it doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my chrome extension by adding a babel-loader to my webpack config, so my extension works fine on YouTube now.

But that still leaves the question, why don't ES6 Custom Elements work on Youtube from the browser console? I'm still confused by that

Comment: The error is in the polyfill, so it looks like IF the polyfill is used you can't go native. If you do native you don't want the polyfill, so don't load it then. It looks like YouTube serves the same code to all browsers.. ofcourse.. because they converted YouTube to use components over 2 years ago... so they had to use the polyfill, because v1 wasn't finished yet. I don't know (I refuse to do polyfill development nowadays) maybe [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io) can sniff the polyfill. So for your YouTube extension you need to use ES5 code. YouTube forced the polyfill on your Browser client.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer. Because of [custom-elements-es5-adapter](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs), customElements.define() and customElements.get() are redefined. Fortunately we can acces the original methods:

```
customElements.constructor.prototype.define.call(customElements, "test-element", TestElement);
```